# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in a procedure which will add data in 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Add_Game` (IN Game_Name_ip VARCHAR(100),IN            Genre_ip  ENUM('Controllers', 'Extreme Sports', 'Action & Adventure', 'Racing',      'RPG', 'Baseball', 'Sports', 'Systems', 'Puzzle', 'Fighting', 'Strategy', 'FPS', 'Wrestling', 'Accessories', 'Soccer', 'Other', 'Football', 'Party', 'Arcade', 'Basketball', 'Simulation', 'Music'),
        IN Rating_ip ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),IN Platform_Name_ip      ENUM('N64', 'NES', 'Super Nintendo', 'Gamecube', 'Wii', 'Playstation 1', 'Playstation 2', 'Playstation 3', 'Xbox', 'Xbox 360', 'Sega Genesis', 'Atari 2600', 'Gameboy Color', 'Gameboy Advance'),IN Completeness_Type_ip ENUM('B', 'I', 'C', 'BC', 'BI', 'IC', 'BIC'), IN Condition_ip ENUM('New', 'Mint', 'Very Good', 'Good', 'Acceptable', 'Poor'),
         IN Purchase_Date_ip DATE,IN Purchase_Price_ip DECIMAL(4,2))
        BEGIN
         DECLARE Game_key int;
          DECLARE MyCollection_Key int;
        DECLARE Platform_Key int;
         START TRANSACTION;
          INSERT INTO videogame_collection_1.video_game(`Game_Name`,   `Genre`,          `Rating`) VALUES (Game_Name_ip, Genre_ip,Rating_ip,Rating_ip);
                   SET Game_key = LAST_INSERT_ID();
                        INSERT INTO videogame_collection_1.mycollection     (`Completeness_Type`, `Condition`, `Purchase_Date`, `Purchase_Price`) VALUES    (Completeness_Type_ip, Condition_ip, Purchase_Date_ip, Purchase_Price_ip);
                               SET MyCollection_Key = LAST_INSERT_ID();
                          INSERT INTO    videogame_collection_1.platform(`Platform_Name`) VALUES (Platform_Name_ip);
                                    SET Platform_Key = LAST_INSERT_ID();
                                INSERT INTO     videogame_collection_1.video_game_platform_mycollection(`MyCollection_Id`, `Game_Id`, `Platform_Id`) VALUES (MyCollection_Key,Game_key,Platform_Key);
                          COMMIT;
                              END
```

I am getting the above error when I try to insert video game addition data from front end to Mysql Database. It will insert the data in 3 different tables. So, how can I implement this?

Comment: Are any of the columns of the table auto-incremented identity columns? If this was the case, you wouldn't specify the value in the insert statement.

Comment: Hi, AUTO_INCREMENT columns are not specified in an Insert statement.

Comment: I meant in the structure of the tables you are inserting into. I see video_game_platform_mycollection has Id fields, are these auto incremented? It just seems that the error would be related to something like that since for all of your insertion statements, the number of columns match the number of values inserted.

Comment: I am storing values of AUTO_INCREMENT columns in 3 variables which are declared. That values I am putting in my Bridge Table video_game_platform_mycollection

Answer (score 0):

In this statement you are entering the Rating_ip value twice:

```
  INSERT INTO videogame_collection_1.video_game(`Game_Name`,   `Genre`,          `Rating`) VALUES (Game_Name_ip, Genre_ip,Rating_ip,Rating_ip);
```

It should read:

```
  INSERT INTO videogame_collection_1.video_game(`Game_Name`,   `Genre`,          `Rating`) VALUES (Game_Name_ip, Genre_ip,Rating_ip);
```

You receive the error because you were trying to insert 4 columns worth of data into an insert statement in which you were only specifying 3 columns.